# How to get the list of email addresses present in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, azure-active-directory, office365, email-validation

I have created a project using .Net core and If I type any name or email in the 'User' textbox field which is in one of my pages, I have to match the name and fetch the list of users available in the outlook's organization domain. So how to get all email address or user list such that is available in the Outlook?

I have tried like the following but I am new to this functionality and I don't know how to connect our Outlook account and fetch the address list. Could anyone help me with this?

```
public static void DisplayAccountInformation(Application application)
{

        // The Namespace Object (Session) has a collection of accounts.
        Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts;

        // Concatenate a message with information about all accounts.
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop over all accounts and print detail account information.
        // All properties of the Account object are read-only.
        foreach (Account account in accounts)
        {

            // The DisplayName property represents the friendly name of the account.
            builder.AppendFormat("DisplayName: {0}\n", account.DisplayName);

            // The UserName property provides an account-based context to determine identity.
            builder.AppendFormat("UserName: {0}\n", account.UserName);

            // The SmtpAddress property provides the SMTP address for the account.
            builder.AppendFormat("SmtpAddress: {0}\n", account.SmtpAddress);

            // The AccountType property indicates the type of the account.
            builder.Append("AccountType: ");
            switch (account.AccountType)
            {

                case OlAccountType.olExchange:
                    builder.AppendLine("Exchange");
                    break;

                case OlAccountType.olHttp:
                    builder.AppendLine("Http");
                    break;

                case OlAccountType.olImap:
                    builder.AppendLine("Imap");
                    break;

                case OlAccountType.olOtherAccount:
                    builder.AppendLine("Other");
                    break;

                case OlAccountType.olPop3:
                    builder.AppendLine("Pop3");
                    break;
            }

            builder.AppendLine();
        }

        // Display the account information.

 }
```

And I called the function by passing my domain name,

```
var application = new Application();
application.CreateObject("outlook.office365.com");
DisplayAccountInformation(application);
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Could you please explain why your code is not working as intended?

Comment: Error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The operation failed.' - And the code line: "application.CreateObject("outlook.office365.com");". The things here is I don't know how to specify my domain and server and my code is right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult getADEmail(string query = "")
    {
        DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(mail=" + query + "*))";

        SearchResult srEmail = dirSearcher.FindOne();
        SearchResultCollection SearchResultCollection = dirSearcher.FindAll();
        string propName = "mail";
        ResultPropertyValueCollection valColl = srEmail.Properties[propName];

        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        foreach (SearchResult sr in SearchResultCollection)
        {
            ResultPropertyValueCollection val = sr.Properties[propName];
            results.Add(val[0].ToString());
        }

        return Json(results);
    }
```

Comment: This code is working fine in my local but not working in IIS server. (i.e) After hosted my application to an IIS server, due to some permission issues, the directory searcher is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the proper method to get the users' list.

The easiest way is [listing users through Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

You could have a quick test in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

If you want to know how to implement in C# with Microsoft Graph SDK, refer to the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request). (Select the C# tab)

[image]

**BUT**, I still don't think it's necessary to match the name by yourself **if** you are trying to implement the sign in process.

The OAuth requests should be handled with Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL), See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial#implementing-oauth2).

You need to take a close look into [OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant flow with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

Comment: How to pass the parameter authprovider? is it a bearer token from Active Directory ?